# How to handle this situation in a JSP rendered by a servlet ?(if I have something to show and if I have to print an error message)

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am very new in Java Web Application development and I have the following problem with a Servlet based webapp.

So I have an **HttpServlet** that handle request toward the URL pattern:

```
http://localhost:7001/edi-mon/salwf.do
```

that render a view like this implemented using a **JSP** page that contains **JQuery** showing an accordion menu:

[image]

Each accordion section contains the information related to an object having class **SalDettaglio** that is into an array retrieved from the servlet (using a web service) ad putted into section

Before render this view (the table containing some informations) my servlet infact contact a web service obtaining an **Out** object that contains the web service response.

This **Out** object contains inside it 2 objects that are:

1. An array of **SalDettaglio** object that I use to render my accordion menu (each object for each accordion section).
2. An **Esito** object that contains the status of the web service response (it could be **OK** if the webservice call is succesfull or **KO** if the webservice call failed).

So actually my **servlet** contains a **service()** method like this:

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LoggerMDC.setup(req, res);
        Logger logger = (Logger) Logger.getStdLogger(Monitoraggio.class); // do not declare 'logger' as static field in order to work with MDC

        String service = req.getParameter("serv");
        String matricola = req.getParameter("matricola");
        char serviceId = Utility.getServizio(req.getParameter("serv"));

        // Retrieve the web service output:
        Out reportSal = getSalReport(matricola,"","");

        // The collection that have to be shown in a table inside the JSP view:
        SalDettaglio[] salDettaglio = reportSal.getSal();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("salDettaglio", salDettaglio);

        gotoPage(ConfigurationFactory.getPropertiesPages().getProperty("pagina_salwf"), req, res);

}
```

So as you can see in the previous code first I retrieve the webservice response (the **Out** object), then from it I retrieve the inner **SalDettaglio[]** array and so I put this array into the session so I can use it in my JSP page to render the accordion, in this way:

```
<div id="accordion">

    <%
    for (SalDettaglio salDettaglio : (SalDettaglio[]) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("salDettaglio")) {
    %>
        <h2>
            ACCORDION HEADER
        </h2>

        <div>
            ACCORDION CONTENT
        </div>
</div>
```

So in this way I show the accordion menu containing the information related to the objet into the **SalDettaglio[]** array but, in this way, I am not considering the webservice status that is into the previous **Out.Esito** object.

For example if the **Out.Esito** value is **KO** and not **OK** I will have an empty **SalDettaglio[]** array and I have not to show the accordion menu but I want to show an error message using AJAX (for example a popup or something like this)

How to handle this situation?

I am not very expert about these topics and I don't know if my idea could be a smart solution.

I am thinking that I can do the following thing:

1. Inside the **service()** method of my servlet I put the entire **Out** object (the webservice response that contains inside it the **SalDettaglio[]** array and the **Esito** object that represents the webservice status) and not only the **SalDettaglio[]** array.
2. Then in my view if the **Out.Esito** value is **OK** I show the accordion menu acceding to the **Out.SalDettaglio[]** object. While if the **Out.Esito** value is **KO** I don't show the accordion but an error message into my page.

Could be a smart solution or am I missing something?

Comment: Your solution is ok. Put both the array and result status on the jsp. Then based on status show table or error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show an error message in jsp page that was send from a servlet and to display it in jsp page the code must be similar to this one:

```
<% if(!request.getAttribute("errorMessage").isEmpty()){
 out.println(requet.getAttribute("errorMessage"));
} %>
```

the errorMessage attribute must be defined in the servlet that send the request to the jsp page, or if you are using jquery you can send it from a PrintWriter in the servlet and write the script that will be displayed in the jsp file. I hope my answer can help you